# Error creating table in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So I am importing a bunch of data into a sheet and then I want to make it into a table. I do not know how many rows of data there will be. This code was working correctly a few days ago, but I suppose I might have unwittingly changed something. Here is the code:

```
Sheets("Enrollment Data Aggregate").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range([A1].End(xlDown), "$n$1"), , xlYes).Name = "EDA_Table"
```

I am getting an error message that says "The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table." As far as I know, I am making the table on the same page as where the data is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to have a range object declared, so that you can access its properties.

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Enrollment Data Aggregate")
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wks.Range([A1].End(xlDown), "$n$1")
wks.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "EDA_Table"
```

Comment: So, now it gives me an error and highlights the fourth line. It says "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed".

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the newest edition? Refresh the page and try again :-)

Comment: Everything is working! Thank you! I also looked and found out that I had a named range that might have been messing things up. I'm not sure, but I didn't need it so I deleted it. I ran the macro again and everything worked. Thank you! And for some reason I can't mark your answer as accepted. A box shows up that says an error has occurred. I think it has something to do with reputation points?

Comment: Glad it worked. I guess you can try again later, should be possible for everyone to accept an answer :-)

Comment: I will do that later when I can get it to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Function/Sub/Code, that converts your Range to Table, is put in the same sheet in which you intend to have the table on the VBA Project window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also solve the bug by specifying the range in the table.

For example, changing:

`Sheets("Enrollment Data Aggregate").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range([A1].End(xlDown), "$n$1"), , xlYes).Name = "EDA_Table"`

To:

`Sheets("Enrollment Data Aggregate").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets("Enrollment Data Aggregate").Range([A1].End(xlDown), "$n$1"), , xlYes).Name = "EDA_Table"`